# How to compare C# now to SQL Server datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How do you compare C# now to SQL Server datetime?

I have tried ten things, but nothing works:

```
string sql;
DataTableReader dr;
sql = "Select StartDate from mytable";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB"]);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dr = dt.CreateDataReader();

var now = DateTime.Now.Date;

while (dr.Read())
{
    // StartDate datatype is a SQL Server datetime and possibly can be null
    if(dr["StartDate"] < now) 
    {
        // code for start date is in the past
    }
}
```

Comment: cast dr["StartDate"] to DateTime first and then compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert SQL Server string to datetime.

```
// StartDate datatype is a SQL Server datetime and possibly can be null
if(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["StartDate"]) < now) 
{
    // code for start date is in the past
}
```

Comment: This works!, but I get this error on records that have null StartDate. System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: @Austin Check if it's DBNull before you try to convert it.

Comment: Here is the working code incase anyone is interested, if (DBNull.Value.Equals(dr["StartDate"]) || Convert.ToDateTime(dr["StartDate"]) < now), thanks everyone

Comment: you can also use if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["StartDate"]) ){}